# Ctrl-Z sent to Fedora server over telnet does not stop the process

Tags: ios, shell, unix, telnet, terminal-emulator

Objective:

I am working on an iOS terminal emulator for accessing my Unix server through the telnet protocol. I am testing against both AIX and Fedora Linux.

Problem:

If I send Ctrl-Z (ASCII 26) to the AIX server, it behaves as expected: I get back a string like `stopped programname`, and then any further characters I send get echoed back.

When I send it to the Fedora server, I get no echo-back until I send Ctrl-Z a second time. The program is running under Bash on the Fedora machine.

Why am I seeing this difference in behavior?

Comment: Difference behaviour  between AIX and "Red Hat" explain by a example

`I ran the command "yes hello". So hello was printing on the screen until i press "CTRL+Z" to abort it. So i sent the appropriate code for CTRL+Z which is 26.
In case of AIX it will return some data "stopped  yes hello" and after this if i pressed any character , server send back result.
In case of "Red Hat" i received DM (242). After this each character i pressed, do not display back from the server until i press CTRL+Z again.`

Comment: I am using BASH cell.

Comment: Are you *certain* the program is running under Bash? Have you opened another terminal and run a command like `ps -e --forest` to check its parentage?

Comment: Does it work correctly if you use an interactive `telnet` program from another machine?

Comment: @WarrenYoung Yes, I am sure about "Bash". I have a software in which this(ps -e --forest) command run same as in my emulator. Yes it work correctly in another machine telnet program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 calls:

1. Stopping that process

   `kill -SIGSTOP 'pgrep process_name'`
2. Continuing that process

   `kill -SIGCONT 'pgrep process_name'`

> SIGSTOP tells a process to “hold on” and SIGCONT tells a process to
>   “pick up where you left off”

See, if that help.

Comment: How this can be accomplished in telnet emulation because i don't know the  `process_name`.

Comment: So, on what basis you are suspending process? or How do you know which process to suspend.

Comment: I ran the command `yes hello`. So hello was printing on the screen until i press "CTRL+Z" to abort it. So i sent the appropriate code for CTRL+Z which is 26. In return i received  DM (242). After this each character i pressed, do not display back from the server until i press CTRL+Z again.

Comment: ok, I have got list of startTime of process and tty and command_name and PID

Comment: Great! that you can fetch few of the process by doing something like: head -n 5, that will give you 5 entry. On that basis you can then kill them.