# how to send keys with control into vt220?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unix, telnet

I am working on a terminal emulator for accessing my unix server.

I don't know how to send keys with controls such as "CTRL+Z", do i need to send it as control sequence or a plain value?

Comment: WOW! I was using a real vt220 when I was at the age of my son now! May I ask why use 30 years old technology, and if you absolutely must - why not use one of the existing apps? As a general note - CTRL-Z is ASCII 26 and this could be googled. But the question is too general - perhaps you should make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> is [ASCII code 26](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters). So, you simply send a byte, valued 26.

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380426/ctrl-z-does-not-work-in-case-of-aix-server for my actual problem.

Comment: I don't see that that other question affects whether this one is answered correctly. You asked a question, and I have confirmed that you are sending the correct value. This does mean that your other question involves a certain amount of confusion, but the place to address that confusion is in the other question.

Comment: i know as per my question your answer is correct.but help me for this also,
"i am also sending this code but after this i have type any character then  server doesn't give me any response until don't send CTRL+Z(26) code."